# How to extract Java Android sources and integrate in another project

Tags: java, android, android-resources

We are developing a java based framework, running on Linux OS
that will provide an infrastructure for developed Applications (Java)
which is very similar to Android OS architecture. 
Our framework consists of services and data providers running as different processes and providing
data to the applications running also in the system.
We want to use frameworks/base sources from the Android OS and use it in our framework 
after some modifications, without building the entire Android OS.
Is this task possible to achieve in a reasonable amount of time?
If so, can you please point us where to start?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a portion without needing to rebuild everything i think you could trying using AOP and compile time weaving, that is AspectJ in your case. Have a look [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://eclipse.org/aspectj/&ei=TZYlUvXPAY_20gWrs4HoBA&usg=AFQjCNHk1JQliSyKxpQjX4Ke4GypV6Hofw&sig2=_JBDO-3XoF-OaORPuYCdCA&bvm=bv.51495398,d.d2k).